Merge cells in ag grid excel export
The task is to export an Excel file from aggrids so that adjacent cells with the same values ​​are merged into one.
How can I merge cells with the same values ​​in ag grid excel export?
Rowspan not working in excel export
Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.
How can I use merge accross?
current version of Grid 32, Angular framework
Excel Example

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
